# passing template function to std::for_each

Tags: c++, templates, foreach, stl, functor

I am trying to write a simple template function that prints every element of some container, without using for loops. So far, I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T> void print_with_space(T x){
  std::cout << x << ' ';
}

template <typename T> void print_all(T beg, T end){
  std::for_each(beg, end, print_with_space<int>);
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(){
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<int> v(a, a+3);
  print_all(v.begin(), v.end());
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs, but only because I put `print_with_space<int>` inside the implementation of `print_all`. I would like to just have `print_with_space` there for obvious reasons, but then the code doesn't compile. How do I do this?

Comment: Replace with `[&](T const& x){print_with_space(x);}`

Comment: I put that as the third argument in for_each, and it doesn't compile with g++ -std=c++11

Comment: [See this proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html).

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper That wouldn't affect this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
std::for_each(beg, end, [](const typename T::value_type& value) {
    print_with_space(value);
});
```

`T` is of type `std::vector<>::iterator`, which is a `RandomAccessIterator`. Every `RandomAcessIterator` has a underlying type, which is exposed by `value_type`.

So, if you pass `std::vector<int>::iterator`, `std::vector<int>::iterator::value_type` would be an `int`.

Now that you have the type, you can make a lambda, which will get executed for every iteration.

---

In C++14, you can even do:

```
//'auto' automatically deduces the type for you
std::for_each(beg, end, [](const auto& value) {
    print_with_space(value);
});
```

Comment: I had to put `typename` before the T::value_type: `std::for_each(beg, end, [](typename T::value_type& val){print_with_space(val);});` and it worked with std=c++11

Comment: @xdavidliu For me it worked without `typename`, oh well :)

Comment: Actually iterators do not have to define `value_type` type alias. In fact, pointers satisfy `RandomAccessIterator` concept, but obviously they do not have any member types. It might be better to switch to C++14 and make polymorphic lambda, if you do not want to mess with iterator traits.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I don't really get what you are trying to say, [RandomAccessIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) have to have a member `value_type`.

Comment: or simply `const auto& value` in c++14 for generic lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 Jup, helpful for those who use C++14 :)

Comment: Your link does not have the requirement for type to have a member `value_type`. And neither does Standard. In fact it explicitely does not require type to have such member by stating that pointers are random access iterators.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot My link does state it: `The type It satisfies RandomAccessIterator if: - [...] - value_type, the type denoted by std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` But I didn't know that about the standard, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: And where it says that `It` must have member type? It talks only about `iterator_traits` which does not always use member type and can be specialized for user types.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I think I see what you mean. I though that it was required, my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
template <typename T> void print_all(T beg, T end) {
    std::for_each(beg, end, print_with_space<decltype(*beg)>);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for C++03:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename T> void print_all(T beg, T end)
{
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type val_t;  
  std::for_each(beg, end, print_with_space<val_t>);
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: this works. I just realized that I can also do `std::for_each(beg, end, print_with_space<typename T::value_type>);` and it works for C++03

Comment: @xdavidliu as I mentioned in another answer comment, iterators do not have to declare `T::value_type`. Think about pointers (and that in release configurations vector iterators are sometimes pointers). It is better to use `iterator_traits`, which should work with any conforming iterators.

Comment: got it; `print_with_space<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>` allows doing `int a[] = {1, 2, 3}; print_all(a, a+3);`, which would not be possible with the first method

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible solution, which will work with all versions of c++, is to make `print_with_space` a function object.

This confers a number of advantages:

1. no need to specify template type at call site.
2. no need to fiddle around with manual type deduction.
3. partial specialisation can be achieved by having the functor defer to a templated free function.

Such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// basic implementation
template<class T> void impl_print_with_space(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}

// what about special handling for strings?

template<class C, class Ch, class Alloc>
void impl_print_with_space(const std::basic_string<C, Ch, Alloc>& x)
{
    std::cout << std::quoted(x) << ' ';
}

// functor

struct print_with_space
{
  template<class T> void operator()(const T& x) const
  {
    impl_print_with_space(x);
  }
};


template <typename Iter> void print_all(Iter beg, Iter end)
{
  std::for_each(beg, end, print_with_space());
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(){
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<int> v(a, a+3);
  print_all(v.begin(), v.end());

  auto b = std::vector<std::string> { "hello", "world" };
  print_all(b.begin(), b.end());

  return 0;
}
```